# How to extract the first 5 rows for each id user in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group, top-n

I have only one table where I want to extract the first 5 rows for each `ID_USER`.

I execute the following query:

```
SELECT
      ID_USER as U_ID_USER,
      COUNT(ID_USER) as NUM_TIC
FROM
     TABLE_USERS
GROUP BY ID_USER
ORDER BY ID_USER
```

Which returns the following information when run:

```
U_ID_USER   NUM_TIC
16469       34
29012       4
33759       2
```

Then I want to put each value of `ID_USER` in the following query for extract only the first 5 rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT
       DATE,
       ID_USER,
       C1,
       C2,
       C3
FROM 
       TABLE_USERS
WHERE
      ID_USER = '16469'
ORDER BY ID_USER)
WHERE ROWNUM < 6;
```

For example for the `ID_USER` "16469" returns the following information when run:

```
DATE       ID_USER   C1   C2   C3
13/12/17   16469     X    X    X
11/12/17   16469     X    X    X
07/12/17   16469     X    X    X
04/12/17   16469     X    X    X
01/12/17   16469     X    X    X
```

That I want is an automatic process in PL/SQL or an query that give me an output like this:

```
DATE       ID_USER   C1   C2   C3
13/12/17   16469     X    X    X
11/12/17   16469     X    X    X
07/12/17   16469     X    X    X
04/12/17   16469     X    X    X
01/12/17   16469     X    X    X
25/12/17   29012     X    X    X
20/12/17   29012     X    X    X
15/11/17   29012     X    X    X
10/11/17   29012     X    X    X
18/12/17   33759     X    X    X
15/12/17   33759     X    X    X
```

Is it possible to get this output with PL/SQL or with a query?

Comment: As a general (and trivial) suggestion - if you want rows from 1 to 5, use `<= 5` rather than `< 6`. The intent is much clearer to someone else who is reading your query and is trying to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT date, id_user, c1, c2, c3
FROM (SELECT u.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_user ORDER BY date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table_users u
     )
WHERE seqnum <= 5;
```

When you use `rownum`, then it returns that many rows from the result set.  `ROW_NUMBER()` is different.  This is a function that enumerates the rows.  It starts with "1" for each `id_user` (based on the `PARTITION BY` clause).  The row with the highest date gets the value of one, the second highest 2, and so on -- based on the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with `row_number`.

```
SELECT DATE,ID_USER,C1,C2,C3
FROM (SELECT
       T.*
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID_USER ORDER BY DATECOL DESC) AS RNUM
      FROM TABLE_USERS T
     ) T
WHERE RNUM < 6
```